# Window do not accept key press after ShowWindow(browserPtr, 3)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi

My goal is to dock browser window from another process
into my application.

I have a panel hwnd that will be a parent, and hwnd of browser window.

Here is a code:

```
ShowWindow(browserPtr, 3);
SetParent(browserPtr, browserContainerPanel.Handle);
MoveWindow(browserPtr, 0, 0, browserContainerPanel.Width, browserContainerPanel.Height, true);
```

In this case browser window became a child, and placed correctly. 
But it stopped accepting keyboard input and cannot gather the focus.

If I don't call ShowWindow - all works correctly except window position and size. 
Wihout ShowWindow I cannot set size and position. MoveWindow just ignored.

Why docked window do not accepts user input?
What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE

Current My code:

```
/// Attach container app input thread to the running app input thread, so that
///  the running app receives user input.
FAppThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, new IntPtr());
AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), FAppThreadID, true);

/// Changing parent of the running app to our provided container control
SetParent(window, container);
SendMessage(container, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
UpdateWindow(window);

/// Make the running app to fill all the client area of the container
SetWindowPos(window, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, SWP_NOZORDER);
SetForegroundWindow(window);
```

But in this case window size is ignored for some reason. However there is everything ok with focus and input. How to fix sizes?

Comment: What is 3? Why aren't you using the `SW_` constants?

Comment: I used it under .net, and I don't know any such constants there. 3 is the value of SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED and SW_MAXIMIZE constants. So there is no any difference here.

Comment: The parent and child windows need to have some sort of way to manage input. You need to use an appropriate hosting interface on the browser window, but since you didn't say what browser you're using, there isn't much more than can be said.

Comment: It is a mozilla browser component.

Comment: This is practically impossible to achieve. You've got two processes, two input threads and you try to make it look like a single app. Find a different solution. You won't be able to make this one work.

Comment: I don't have another choice. It is almost working except initial window size. Window has incorrect size right after embedding, but if i resize container - window will update and all displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should also call SetFocus on the browser window in order to send user input to it.